# React state management when route changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have the menu bar at left side and it has 2 navigation links:

1) FetchEmployes: It calls API and it normally takes 1-2 minutes to run( I am showing loader during this time)

2) Transaction: It is a normal Crud Page.

So what I want is, When user comes to FetchEmployee page and calls the API which takes 2 minutes to get the data. I want to allow user to navigates to some other pages to do anywork and when user comes back after 2 minutues then loader should keep on running( or show the data if API call gets completed). I dont want to create a new instance of FetchEmployee class everytime.

Comment: Can't see your problem, why can't you just do it?

Comment: Here the problem is, If user came back to FetchEmployees page then page gets rerender.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and making sure that you block any further action of the FetchEmployes until you have an answer from the server.